# How to move to the next row in a DataGrid (C# / WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

As the title said, I don't understand how works a DataGrid, let me explain with my code :

```
public class User
{
    public string NumeroTIC { get; set; }

    public string NumeroCNT1 { get; set; }

    public string NumeroCNT2 { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

List<User> ImpulseData = new List<User>();
ImpulseData.Add(new User() { NumeroTIC = hex2, NumeroCNT1 = hex4, NumeroCNT2 = hex6, Date = DateTime.Now });
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { dgSimple.ItemsSource = ImpulseData; }));
```

So, I would like to move to an another row each time my class is called, for example, I call my class a 1st time it's writing in the first row, I call it a second time it's writing in the second row, etc..
Currently my code works fine but always in the same row

The variables : hex2,hex4,hex6, are bytes from a serial port but it doesn't matter

Comment: Do not create a new `List<User>` instance each time you want to add an element. Instead, create an `ObservableCollection<User>` and assign it to the ItemsSource property *only once*. Then later add elements to that collection.

Comment: As @Clemens points out you should add all User objects to the same ObservableCollection. But what exactly does "move to the next row" mean?

Comment: To @mm8 : Okay so my soft have to get some info from a serialport. Each time the serialport is used i want to put the data in my datagrid

Comment: Could you please post all code of the class where the ImpulseData list is defined?

Comment: I'm afraid to say something idiot but, it's never defined in fact, it's defined at the last line where Dispartcher.blabla is called

Comment: and if could explain a bit how works ObservableCollection ? Now idea how i could use it

Answer (score -1):

Use Insert instead Add

```
int myIndex;

ImpulseData.Insert(myIndex ,new User() { NumeroTIC = hex2, NumeroCNT1 = hex4, NumeroCNT2 = hex6, Date = DateTime.Now });
```

Comment: that doesn't help when the list is recreated. OP has to access the _existing_ list first

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your code, if you want to use the same list declare ImpulseData in the form class not in your method.

Comment: I haven't written any code. If you have suggestions for the Original Poster, you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43522118/edit) your answer and add that information

Comment: "I don't understand your code", but you still write an answer? Using Insert instead of Add is nonsense. Please don't write an answer when you haven't understood the problem.